# How to launch app when clicked on icon in Android?

Tags: android, gridview, android-activity, launcher

Hey guys right now I'm working on a launcher app. I've made a code where I can display all installed apps in a `GridView` but when I click the icon nothing happens, so how can I launch app from it? Here's my code:

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.appgrid;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    GridView mGrid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        loadApps();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.myGrid);
        mGrid.setAdapter(new AppsAdapter());
    }

    private List<ResolveInfo> mApps;

    private void loadApps() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        mApps = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
    }


    public class AppsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        public AppsAdapter() {
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView i;

            if (convertView == null) {
                i = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
                i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                i.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(95, 95));
                i.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            } else {
                i = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            ResolveInfo info = mApps.get(position);
            i.setImageDrawable(info.activityInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager()));

            return i;
        }

        public final int getCount() {
            return mApps.size();
        }

        public final Object getItem(int position) {
            return mApps.get(position);
        }

        public final long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.appgrid.MainActivity" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/myGrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:gravity="center">

    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try creating an intent and starting it

Comment: I tried before in a sample project but it didn't worked can you show me an example? Please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Comment: But how to use this code? Can you please show me by implementing this in my above given code? I'll sure accept your answer!!!

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/launch-an-application-from-another-application-on-android

Comment: But dear where should I implement those two lines of code?

Comment: in the onclicklistener of the imageicon of the app